# How to stop browser back button using react js hooks and history api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to disable back button after successful login into the application but couldn't make it.
I'm using react router dom 5.2.0 for routing.
Currently, I'm redirecting to login page if someone clicks to browser back button but I need to block the back button.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (history.action === "POP") {
      history.replace('/login');
    }
  };   
}, [history]);
```

Comment: Did you check out my answer? Consider giving some feedback, greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can stop the browser's back button

```
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
   window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fully disable the browsers back button, you can only prevent it from going back like you are doing.

When you are doing this, don't forget to listen for events on `history`, try this out:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return history.listen(() => { // listen
    if (history.action === "POP") {
      history.replace("/login");
    }
  });
}, [history]);
```

Comment: i am trying to block or disable the back button ,so that it can't go back

Comment: There is no way to fully disable the browsers back button, you can only prevent them from going back.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me :

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if (history.action === 'POP') {
            history.go(1);
        }
    };
}, [history]);
```